# File write and file read in utf-16 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, codec

I have this file write function:

```
def filewrite(folderpath, filename, strdata, encmode):
try:
    path = os.path.join(folderpath, filename)
    if not path:
        return
    create_dir_path(folderpath)
    #path = os.path.join(folderpath, filepath)

    with codecs.open(path, mode='w', encoding=encmode) as fp:
        fp.write(unicode(strdata))
except Exception, e:
    raise Exception(e)
```

which am using to write data to a file:

```
filewrite(folderpath, filename, strdata, 'utf-16')
```

But, when if try to read this file am getting the exception:

```
Exception: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM
```

My file read function is as show below:

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=4096):
try:
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
except Exception, ex:
    raise ex


def fileread(folderPath, fileName, encmode):
try:
    path = os.path.join(folderPath, fileName)
    fileData = ''
    if os.access(path, os.R_OK):
        with codecs.open(path, mode='r', encoding=encmode) as fp:
            for block in read_in_chunks(fp):
                fileData = fileData + block
        return fileData
    return ''
except Exception, ex:
    raise ex
```

Please, let me know what am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. Running it on my machine creates the proper BOM at the start of the file automatically.

BOM is a sequence of bytes at the start of the file that indicates which order multi-byte encodings (UTF-16) should be read - you can read about [system endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) if you're interested.

If you're running on a mac/linux you should be able to `hd your_utf16file` or `hexdump your_utf16file` to check the raw bytes inside the file. Running your code I saw the correct bytes 0xff 0xfe at the beginning of mine.

Try replacing your `fileread` function portion with

```
    with codecs.open(path, mode='r', encoding=encmode) as fp:
        for block in fp:
            print block
```

to ensure you can still read the file after eliminating external factors (your `read_in_chunks` functional).

Comment: Am on x64 machine (Windows 8.1). Tried removing `read_in_chunks` as well. Can't get it to work for some reason.

Comment: Is it `codecs.open(path, mode='r', encoding=encmode) as fp:` raising that exception? Make sure you replace `raise ex` with just `raise`, otherwise it masks the true location where the exception started.